# D3 data() calls doesnt trigger the exit() on elements but the enter() works

Tags: d3.js

D3 appends elements on .enter() only but never remove them on .exit()

I have an Array of objects like:

```
arr = [{name:"a"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"},{name:"d"}]
```

then use it initialy on my selection

```
.selectAll("rect").data(arr)
```

Then on a click I do the same again with partly spliced array as the data.

But D3 always only creates the given data as Elements but never removing it on exit(). Also never updating. Just recreating

```
const g = d3.select(this.svgElement.nativeElement).append("g");

const rects = g
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(meta, function(d) {
      console.log('data', d);
      return d.name;
    });


rects
    .exit()
    // .transition(t500)
    .each(function (d, i) { console.log('x rect exit', i, d); })
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .remove()
;

rects
    .each(function (d, i) { console.log('x rect update', i, d); })
    .attr("fill", "green")
;

rects
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .each(function (d, i) { console.log('x rect enter', i, d); })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return i * (rw + gap);
    })
    // .transition(t500)
    .attr("width", rw)
    .attr("height", rh)
    .style("fill", "white")
;
```

I would like to reuse the existing elements with new data and remove the left overs. Seems simple in all examples. But I dont see my Mistake.

Hope you see more than me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards
Gregor

Comment: I'm assuming your code block is part of an update function. Do you append a new `g` every time you run the update function - because it will always be empty when appending it initially, so you will be entering every item every time because `g.selectAll("rect")` will be empty. If everything is entered, exit and update are empty.

Comment: Yes, I do`! ... of course. This make sense. I ll check it out. Thanks. :)